# Pass List of Objects as data

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

So, I am trying to visualize some data that is available to me throguh an api.

The data looks something like this and is a return of an http request:

```
[
    {
    "someID": "1111",
    "otherID": "9999",
    "name": "SomeName",
    "aTotal": "32",
    "bTotal": "16000",
    "cTotal": "800",
    "rank": "1",
    "lastactivity": "44 h",
    "timestamp": "0"
     },
     {
    "someID": "01234",
    "otherID": "9876",
    "name": "SomeName",
    "aTotal": "63",
    "bTotal": "2300",
    "cTotal": "950",
    "rank": "2",
    "lastactivity": "12.11.",
    "timestamp": "0"
     }
]
```

where the list continues with several hundred objects.
someId and other ID are unique.

Whtat I would like to achieve is a plot which displays the name of the objects ("name") on the X-Axis, and the data displayed on the Y-Axis should be any of the other values, let's say aTotal.
It would be cool to be able to display several Y-Values at the same time for the same X-values ("names").

I hope I was able to describe what's my goal and what my data looks like :)

So far I have tried this, which results in an empty canvas with only a grid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Charts</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    const data = [{
        "someID": "1111",
        "otherID": "9999",
        "name": "SomeName",
        "aTotal": "32",
        "bTotal": "16000",
        "cTotal": "800",
        "rank": "1",
        "lastactivity": "44 h",
        "timestamp": "0"
      },
      {
        "someID": "01234",
        "otherID": "9876",
        "name": "SomeName",
        "aTotal": "63",
        "bTotal": "2300",
        "cTotal": "950",
        "rank": "2",
        "lastactivity": "12.11.",
        "timestamp": "0"
      }
    ];
    const cfg = {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: data.bTotal,
          },
          {
            data: data.aTotal,
          },
          {
            data: data.cTotal,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, cfg);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which gives me an empty grid with no data :/
Any idea why that is?

Thanks for any help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

You'll find an example on [ChartJS's site](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html). If you open the source (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), you'll see how they declare the options. Something along these lines:

```js
const data = [{someID:"1111",otherID:"9999",name:"SomeName",aTotal:"32",bTotal:"16000",cTotal:"800",rank:"1",lastactivity:"44 h",timestamp:"0"},{someID:"01234",otherID:"9876",name:"SomeName",aTotal:"63",bTotal:"2300",cTotal:"950",rank:"2",lastactivity:"12.11.",timestamp:"0"}];
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const cfg = {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: data.map(({someID, name}) => `${name} (${someID})`),
    datasets: [{
        label: 'aTotal',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        data: data.map(({aTotal}) => aTotal),
      },
      {
        label: 'bTotal',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
        data: data.map(({bTotal}) => bTotal),
      },
      {
        label: 'cTotal',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)',
        data: data.map(({cTotal}) => cTotal),
      },
    ],
  },
};

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, cfg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="110"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for!